# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with integral template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, clang++

I have the following C++11 code.

```
#include <type_traits>

using IntType = unsigned long long;

template <IntType N> struct Int {};

template <class T>
struct is_int : std::false_type {};

template <long long N>
struct is_int<Int<N>> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    static_assert (is_int<Int<0>>::value, "");
    return 0;
}
```

Clang++ 3.3 compiles the code but on g++ 4.8.2 static assertion fails

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:5: error: static assertion failed: 
     static_assert (is_int<Int<0>>::value, "");
     ^
$
```

The problem is caused by different integral template parameters. 
Which compiler is right in this case?

Comment: Nice question, that's very subtle.

Comment: Just a note - compiles on VS2010 (changed `using` to a `typedef` however.

Comment: @jrok it's not, this question is about a bug in Clang

Comment: @AlecTeal Oh, so you *know* it's clang's bug? I'm eagerly awaiting your answer. :)

Comment: @jrok having read the C++11 standard for work and knowing it really well, yes. Also my answer has nothing to add if it were compared to the answer already here.

Comment: Who on earth put a -1 against this question?

Comment: [Related clang bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16279)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### The surprise

This is a subtle Clang bug, deeply buried in the Standard. The problem is that in almost all cases, non-type template *arguments* can be converted to the type of the template *parameter*. E.g. the expression `Int<0>` has an `int` literal argument of value `0` that is being converted to the type `unsigned long long` of the template parameter `N`.

**14.8.2 Template argument deduction [temp.deduct]/2 2nd bullet**

> -- Non-type arguments must match the types of the corresponding non-type
>   template parameters, **or must be convertible to** the types of the
>   corresponding non-type parameters as speciﬁed in 14.3.2, otherwise
>   type deduction fails.

Since your class template `is_int<T>` has a partial specialization, we need to look at

**14.5.5.1 Matching of class template partial specializations [temp.class.spec.match]**

> 1 When a class template is used in a context that requires an
>   instantiation of the class, it is necessary to determine whether the
>   instantiation is to be generated using the primary template or one of
>   the partial specializations. **This is done by matching the template
>   arguments of the class template specialization with the template
>   argument lists of the partial specializations**.
>
> 2 A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument
>   list if the template arguments of the partial specialization **can be
>   deduced from** the actual template argument list (14.8.2).

So it would seem that we can proceed to the earlier quote of 14.8.2/2 2nd bullet and match the second specialization (although in that case an even more complicated overload resolution game would have to be played).

### The resolution

However, it turns out (as mentioned by @DyP in the comments) that another clause in the Standard supersedes this:

**14.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type [temp.deduct.type]**

> 17 If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type
>   template-parameter, the non-type templateparameter is used in an
>   expression in the function parameter-list and, if the corresponding
>   template-argument is deduced, **the template-argument type shall match
>   the type of the template-parameter exactly**, except that a
>   template-argument deduced from an array bound may be of any integral
>   type. [ Example:

```
template<int i> class A { / ... / };
template<short s> void f(A<s>);
  void k1() {
  A<1> a;
  f(a); // error: deduction fails for conversion from int to short
  f<1>(a); // OK
}
```

The upshot is that the partial specialization of `is_int` cannot be deduced because it does not take the exact same type (`unsigned long long` vs `long long`) as the `Int` class template's formal non-type template parameter.

You can resolve this by giving the non-type template parameter `N` in the partial specialization of `is_int` the same type as the non-type parameter `N` in the primary template `Int`.

```
template <IntType N>
//        ^^^^^^^^         
struct is_int<Int<N>> : std::true_type {};
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d0ad7b77db02034).

Comment: @DyP [temp.clss.spec]/3 says that `Int<0>` does not need the dance with function templates because `N` is a non-type parameter in the primary template and can be deduced to `1`. The problem is that `is_int<T>` does not have a non-type template parameter in its primary template, but only in its partial specialization. It's the deduction of `N` in this partialization that requires the function template argument deduction and ends up in 14.8.2.5/17

Comment: @DyP indeed it *seems* at first sight, hence the surprise, I tried to clarify in the modified answer. BTW, the process of creating a function type to deduce the parameters of a partially specialized class templates should not be more complicated than writing a function template with the class template specialization as an argument, similar to the overload resolution game (where arguments are deduced for the *other* overloads' parameters, rather than their own parameters).

Comment: [Repost from an earlier comment] [core issue 1770](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1770) addresses 14.8.2.5; the proposed resolution makes clear it applies to *all* deductions, not only to function templates (or maybe it already is clear, and I'm just too nit-picky ;)

Comment: @DyP at least your insistence on full understanding made me dig deeper and I learnt something new today, so thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Clang is being inconsistent. [Since it accepts your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94b4b1df122762ce), I'm expecting the following code must output `f(Int<long long>)` instead of `f(T)`:

```
using IntType = unsigned long long;
template <IntType N> struct Int {};

template<typename T>
void f(T) { std::cout << "f(T)" << std::endl; }

template<long long N>
void f(Int<N>) { std::cout << "f(Int<long long>)" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    f(Int<0>{});
}
```

But surprisingly, it outputs this ([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ad6a48e90adeb1d)):

```
f(T)
```

That shows `Int<0>` does NOT match with the second overload which accepts the argument as `Int<N>`.  If that is so, then why does it match with `Int<N>` when it is used as template argument to the class template (in your case)?

My conclusion:

- If Clang is correct in **my** case, then it is incorrect in **your** case.
- If Clang is correct in **your** case, then it is incorrrect in **my** case.

Either way, Clang seems to have bug.

GCC, on the other hand, is consistent at least. That doesn't prove though that it doesn't have bug  — it might mean that it has bug in both cases! Unless someone comes up with the standardese and showing it has bug *too*, I'm going to trust GCC in this case.

Comment: It's worth noting that GCC has test-cases, loads of them, but loads more in separate folders with "torture" in the name, these contain truly convoluted bits of code that the standard says should or shouldn't work, a program called Deja Gnu verifies errors happen where they ought to and stuff works where it should. Historically GCC has been a sandbox for new C++ documents and creating convoluted code to test is a part of that process.

Comment: Additionally - I'm sure Clang has tests too (it wouldn't have gotten this far if it did not :P) GCC has experience.

Comment: To prove that the second overload doesn't viable for `Int<N>`, you'd have to *remove* the first; otherwise you'd just prove that the first is a *better* match. If you do remove the first overload, an early clang++3.4 (coliru) complains: *"note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure : deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the its corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long long' vs 'long long')"*

Comment: [temp.deduct.type]/17: clang++ correctly rejects the second overload.

Comment: @DyP: How about the code in the question? Is Clang correct then?

Comment: @Nawaz I'm not sure if the class template specialization with the different type for the template-parameter in the OP is viable, but if it is, then deduction during partial ordering would fail (as it is specified in terms of function templates). Also see [core issue 1770](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1770), where the proposed resolution covers this case as well (involuntarily?). There's also a [clang bug report on this issue](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16279)

Comment: @Nawaz Oh.. there *is* only one specialization (and the primary template). So no partial ordering which could fail.

Comment: @DyP: So what is *your* conclusion?

Comment: @Nawaz I'm not entirely happy with the description of matching of partial specialization in the Standard (IMHO it's quite vague); but I think [temp.deduct.type]/17 is *intended* to apply to the matching process as well, in which case clang should reject *both*, the partial specialization and the second overload.