# Template specialization - different results with clang and gcc

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++

I would like to specialize a template struct based on the given type as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename K>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = 1;
};

template<typename K, unsigned CC>
struct Foo<std::array<K,CC>>
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = CC;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo<float>::value << std::endl; // should give 1
    std::cout << Foo<std::array<char,3>>::value << std::endl; // should give 3
}
```

However this produces different results with clang and gcc. I would say that clang gets it right and gcc is wrong.

*Output gcc 4.8.2-19ubuntu1:*

```
1
1
```

*Output clang 3.4-1ubuntu3:*

```
1
3
```

**Questions**:

- Is the observed behaviour a bug with gcc?
- What would be the correct approach / a workaround which also works with gcc?

Comment: what happens if you change `3` to `3u` ?

Comment: I get `1` `3` on g++ 4.8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) second template parameter is `size_t`, not unsigned.

So, if you rewrite your function like

```
template<typename K, std::size_t CC>
struct Foo<std::array<K,CC>>
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = CC;
};
```

both compilers should give equal results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in clang: [g++ and clang++ different behaviour with integral template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268114/g-and-clang-different-behaviour-with-integral-template-parameter?rq=1), http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16279

> 17 - [...] [The] template-argument type shall match the type of the template-parameter exactly, except that a template-argument deduced from an array bound may be of any integral type.

The correct approach is to use `std::size_t` as the integral template parameter type of `Foo`.